# Unable to login through LightDM

Tags: xorg, lightdm, display-manager

After executing the following script (I removed all occurrences of tmp, mind you. Or at least I thought I did) and rebooting the system, I'm no longer able to log in through the display manager.

https://github.com/chrisprobst/ubuntu-raring-haskell/blob/c5b6fcd2f56e010fe30c2bd08624e83bad8813bf/install.sh

At the beginning, I couldn't even use startx without issuing sudo. This was alleviated by "chmod o+t,ugo+rw /tmp" (which leads me to believe I might have run the wrong (the unmodified) version of the script.

Anyways. After issuing the aforementioned chmod command and rebooting the system, I tried logging in again. While logging in from the terminal functions properly now, LightDM will log in, flash the screen twice and return to the login screen.

Is there anything else I could try?

I ran the script in it's entirety (minus installing the non dev libglw1-mesa)

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing `/tmp` in the output of  `ls -l /` command, you can give it proper permission  by typing

`sudo chmod 1777 /tmp` .

Comment: Well. As I said. /tmp already has proper permissions, so it has to be something else.

Comment: You might be correct. There are several .Xauthority files there (SSH cookies, right?) but the main one says "-rw------- root:root" Is it save to set this to "-rw-rw-r--" and my regular user as owner?

Comment: I have deleted one of my comment,Use `sudo chown username:username ~/.Xauthority` and try to login. Also the correct permission of `~/.Xauthority` is `rw-------`. So correct it if needed.

Comment: Thanks. Everything is back to normal now and I even got the haskell-platform installed (ended up doing it manually, since the script was using sources that wouldn't compile). I'm told that this particular ownership issue might have arisen from the fact that I misused sudo to launch several graphical applications.